# AOSP nexus 10 android 7 nougat options?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, vanilla-android, samsung-nexus-10, 7.0-nougat

I'm currently running an early AOSP build of android 6 on nexus 10. What are the aosp options for android 7? I'm not talking about a custom ROM like cyanogenmod. I mean one as close to AOSP as possible.

Comment: Until something drops on XDA, waiting is your best and only option.

Comment: Scanno at omnirom is working on  7, but I'm asking about  a ROM that doesn't have all the baggage of a distribution,  just a few essential fixes to AOSP.

Comment: That's why I said "wait". Are you willing to set up a build environment and compile one yourself?

Comment: I built OmniROM for Android 6, but a considerable amount of work would be needed to take the fixes from OmniROM and make a purer AOSP build and although I have the development experience to make it happen I can't find the time.

Comment: Well that's it. I build CM for devices I own too, but I only build from nightly codes without incorporating any changes or fixing bugs because I don't have time either. I'll just take what I can get, and if the device can't keep up in terms of ROMs (version- or bug-wise), I'd just sell it.

Comment: I'm not selling it!

Comment: Just saying... But with a tablet of this age I'd repurpose it for some other uses instead of forcing it to swallow the latest and greatest with bugs. It's ultimately up to you.

Comment: It only stopped receiving security updates earlier this year from Google and ran 6 acceptably with some help from a Google engineer. If I want a particular build I may have to develop it myself but fixes can be ported from other ROMs